# Google Play Services The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, admob

I have problem here with my app. Eclipse error log show this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's  AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4242000 but found  7327000.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.u.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ag.U(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.ag.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
at com.example.myapp.activities.EditActivity.loadAds(EditActivity.java:201)
at com.example.myapp.activities.EditActivity.onCreate(EditActivity.java:96)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
```

And this is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.myapp.custom.BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
    ...
```

I can not figure out what`s going wrong here :( If I disable AdMob Banner and Interstitial ads (remove IDs from strings) app works fine.

Thank you for any help

Comment: This is a little bit more tricky in Eclipse than in Android Studio.  Did you copy the library folder into your project, or did you link directly to the library folder in the SDK?  Also, check the version.xml in the library.

Comment: I re-importet project and now somehow working :) Strange... Thanks anyway!